# How to have two different asp.net project in the domain/iis site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I have an existing ASP.NET 4.7 application running in IIS on a domain like "microsoft.com".
I create a new ASP.NET CORE project to rewrite this existing application in .NET CORE 2.0.

I'm trying to migrate part by part of this application to deploy controller/action by controller/action rewrited in .NET CORE. 
So I would like, to have the two application running on the server, same site and domain like the following :

https://www.microsoft.com/EN-US target the ASP.NET 4.7 application.
https://www.microsoft.com/EN-US/windows/ target the ASPNET CORE application is in already rewrite in the .NET CORE in the new project.

Is there any way to have these two different application running on the same domain and IIS site?

Comment: Maybe using a sub domain / sub folder and redirect with rules, page by page on IIS has you work on it. And finally replace the old one by the new one ?

Comment: You can, by creating another 'application' under the main application in IIS, but because of web.config inheritance and other reasons, I think it's more complex than it's worth. I would recommend creating a subdomain as a separate site in IIS (eg www.microsoft.com and windows.microsoft.com) and keep them more separate from one another.

Comment: Did a similar exercise to move a project to core.  Approach was a second site with a different subdomain.  The site required authentication so maintaining existing URLs didn't mater as much.  Ported controller by controller.  When new controller was tested and validated in production the old site would be updated to point to the new site and the old controller removed.